# Adding toolTip on mouse hover of info icon in LWC datatable result

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, helptext

I want to add tooltip to a particular column value of data table  on mouse hover. I tried with URL type but the the column value should now be clickable. So I decided to add a info icon and tried to display a custom label value on mouse hover. Anyone have any idea how can I achieve this. Any new idea are also welcome to show tooltip when a value in column not null. Thanks in Advance.

my JS header code

```
contactColumns = [
    {
        label: '',
        type : 'button',
        initialWidth: 60,
        typeAttributes: {
                        iconName: 'utility:check',  
                        iconPosition : 'Right',                           
                        variant : 'base',
                        action :this.updateContactClick
                    }
    }, 
    {type: 'text', label:  this.Label.Name, fieldName: 'Name'},
    {type: 'text', label:  this.Label.Email, fieldName: 'Email'},
    {type: 'text', label:  this.Label.SapNumber, fieldName: 'SAPNumber'},
    {type: 'text', label:  this.Label.LoyaltyId, fieldName: 'loyaltyId',cellAttributes:
    { iconName: { fieldName: 'utility:info' }, iconPosition: 'right' }}, 
    {type: 'text', label:  this.Label.Address, fieldName: 'Address'}
];
```

My apex class response

```
for(Account con : accountMap.values()){
        WrapperSearchResult wrapResult = new WrapperSearchResult();
            wrapResult.Id        = con.Id;
            wrapResult.Name      = con.Name;
            wrapResult.FirstName = con.FirstName;
            wrapResult.LastName  = con.LastName;
            wrapResult.Phone     = con.PersonMobilePhone;
            wrapResult.Email     = con.PersonEmail;
            wrapResult.SAPNumber = con.CC_ON_CustomerNbr__pc; 
            wrapResult.contactId = con.PersonContactId;
            String  address  = con.PersonMailingStreet      != null? con.PersonMailingStreet+' ': '';
                    address += con.PersonMailingCity        != null? con.PersonMailingCity+' ': '';
                    address += con.PersonMailingPostalCode  != null? con.PersonMailingPostalCode+' ': '';
                    address += con.PersonMailingCountry     != null? con.PersonMailingCountry: '';
            wrapResult.Address = address != null? address: '';
            wrapResult.BillingStreet      = con.PersonMailingStreet;
            wrapResult.BillingCity        = con.PersonMailingCity;
            wrapResult.BillingPostalCode  = con.PersonMailingPostalCode;
            wrapResult.BillingCountry     = con.PersonMailingCountry;
            system.debug('Client_ID '+ con.Client_ID__c);
            system.debug('con '+ platformRegistrationInfo.get(con.Client_ID__c));
            wrapResult.LoyaltyId          = platformRegistrationInfo.get(con.Client_ID__c); 
        wrapResultLst.add(wrapResult);
    }
```

Comment: I would also like to add a title or tooltip to cells in `lightning-datable`, and have also come up short so far.  I'm starting to think this is a limitation of `lightning-datatable`.  Side note: your Apex code is probably not relevant here.